# Actionscript connect method and parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Actionscript, in the following code, a flash swf file tries to connect to the FMS server. What are the parameters here? I mean

```
h = host
a = application
r = room
c = I don't know what is this but the value is always 2
t = I do not know what is this parameter. The value is also encrypted 


loc1_.connect("rtmp://"+root.loaderInfo.parameters.h+"/"+root.loaderInfo.parameters.a+"/"+root.loaderInfo.parameters.r,root.loaderInfo.parameters.t,root.loaderInfo.parameters.c);
```

Could you please refer me to any connect method parameters documentation?

Answer (score 0):

you can define a connection by using `NetConnection`

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://myServerName/nameOfFMSapplication/");
```

general syntax of it is `nc.connect(URI, [p1, ..., pN])`

`p1,....pn = list of parameter seprated by comma`

list of parameter defined by application on server, so we can not surely say what are the parameter, before seeing the code of applicatoin.

Comment: So, the parameters could be customized by the application?